# Why does os.symlink uses path relative to destination?

Tags: python

Python 3.7 doc for `os.symlink(src, dst)` is `Create a symbolic link pointing to src named dst.`

Let's imagine this working directory :

```
+-- nb.ipynb
+-- dir1
|   +-- file1
+-- dir2
```

Let's suppose I want to create a symbolic link in `dir2` called `filed2` pointing to `dir1/file1` from my notebook `nb.ipynb`.

In a cell of the notebook, i'll put:

```
import os
os.symlink('dir1/file1', 'dir2/file2')
```

However, this won't work, this will create a file2 in dir2, but when you look at the properties of this file, its `Type` is `Link(broken) (inode/symlink)` and its `Link target` is `dir1/file1`. The Link target is what you put as src in os.symlink.
To achieve the right symlink, one would need to do

```
os.symlink('../dir1/file1', 'dir2/file2')
```

which means that `os.symlink(src, dest)`, `src` should contain the path of the source relative to the destination.

Since I had to create such symlink multiple times, I created this function :

```
def symlink_rel(src, dst):
    rel_path_src = os.path.relpath(src, os.path.dirname(dst))
    os.symlink(rel_path_src, dst)
```

Calling

```
symlink_rel('dir1/file1', 'dir2/file2')
```

will create the right symbolic link. It does seem to me that os.symlink doesn't behave like the documentation says so. Why does `os.symlink` need `src` to be path of `src` relative to `dst` rather than `src` and `dst` to be path from the working directory?

Comment: i agree this can be annoying- personally i use `os.path.abspath()` to ensure the correct full path is used rather than relying on relative paths

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
os.symlink('dir1/file1', 'dir2/file2')
```

Soft links saves the original location of the file which means "dir2/file2" saves the location "dir1/file1". When you cat the file  "dir2/file2" this will search for the "dir1/file1" inside the directory "dir2/" which is the working directory of "file2" and there is no path inside the dir2  called "dir1/file1"

```
os.symlink('../dir1/file1', 'dir2/file2')
```

when you cat this file dir2/file2 , the parent directory of the "file2" is "dir2".
which is same as above. The difference is that ".." means go one directory from where you are standing right now. From that location goto "dir1/file1" so it will work.

> Don't consider your working directory, consider the softlinks parent
> directory and read the location based on that

Comment: What you are saying is absolutely true. However, I find this to be confusing. I lost a good chunk of time trying to figure out why my symlinks were not working. Maybe the documentation of os.symlink should be more precise on that.

Comment: @Statisctic Dean, I add this explaination for the sake of clarity for the new comers.

Comment: It's a good one. At least the people that arrive on this question will know how to proceed. Thank you for that.

Comment: @StatisticDean and FujiKomalan ... for what it's worth, this isn't a Python limitation but a limitation of how symlinks work (at least on linux). Relative paths are always resolved against the location of the symlink itself, not the current directory. Python simply remains faithful to the standard convention.